# Can a method return a set of different return types in a succinct way?

Tags: java

How would I get the string Percent from getData? Is there a way to have getData return multiple strings and request only the ones I choose from it, like if I wanted the percentage number I would call getData("http://woot.com").Percentage?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class Wooot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        needData();
        Report();
    }
    public static void Report() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        while (needData() == true)
        {
            System.out.println(getData("http://woot.com"));
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    public static boolean needData(){
        return true;
    }
    public static String getData(String url) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .get();
        String percent = doc.select(".percent-remaining").first().text();
        String name = doc.select("h2").first().text();
        return name;

    }

}
```

Comment: Unlike C#, where you can put `void getData(out String s1, out String s2)'` in Java you can return only one instance. But you can return a collection (say, array) which contains many items

Comment: If you want to do it exactly as `getData("http://woot.com").Percentage` you're going to have to return a custom class with a percentage property

Comment: What's you want to do with your code?

Comment: To make it clean you should create a new class as return of getData() that contains field percent and name

Comment: I usually use a super lightweight struct-like class to achieve this

Comment: @user230137 I am trying to make a pseudo-tracker for woot.com. I see some great answers below, and am going to read them, I just need to get something done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a class to hold the fields you want back:

```
class SomeData {
    private final String percent;
    private final String name;
    public SomeData(String percent, String name) {
        this.percent = percent;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getPercent() {return percent;}
}
```

It is a valid point that [getters here are not an absolute necessity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786485/217324). Since Java doesn't follow the universal access principle introducing them later can be a little awkward, so I add them in up front. But mostly I do it because my co-workers are used to seeing the getters and I try to avoid weirding them out too much.

You could also add a convenience constructor:

```
    public SomeData(Document document) {
        this(doc.select(".percent-remaining").first().text(),
        doc.select("h2").first().text());
    }
```

This way retrieving the data fields would be in a different place from the connection logic, so you don't have the SRP violation of having multiple reasons for a class to change.

Using some general purpose collection like a Tuple or Map is an option. Tuples are ugly because the names of the fields get discarded. With maps, if entries have different types then the compile-time type-checking gets lost.

Alternatively you could return the Document object instead. I'm not sure introducing a new data holder class here is better than using Document.

Answer (score 1):

## Struct-like object return

There are a few ways you can get "effective" multiple returns. I usually use a lightweight struct-like class to support this

```
public static String getData(String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .get();
    String percent = doc.select(".percent-remaining").first().text();
    String name = doc.select("h2").first().text();
    return new ImportantData(name,percent) ;

}

class ImportantData{
     public final String name;
     public final String percent;  //not sure why the percentage is a string

     public ImportantData(String name, String percent){
          this.name=name;
          this.percentage=percentage;
     }

}
```

This is one of the rare cases where getters add no value and a final field makes more sense.

## Store objects passed as arguments

An alternative I have also seen is to pass a store object to the method. This only works with mutable objects and is far less clear than the Struct-like object return. Make sure to produce clear documentation if using this approach.

```
public static String getData(String url, Vector3d store) throws IOException {
    
    store.x=1;
    store.y=2;
    store.z=3;

    return "someOtherString" ;

}
```

Comment: Ooof, the modify-objects-passed-as-arguments pattern is painful.  Totally fair to mention it as an option, but it should surely be a weapon of last resort.

Comment: @dimo414 I *do* agree. I more mention it because people *should* be aware of it. A graphics library I use makes heavy use of it and the first time I saw it I thought: "What the hell!". However; in its defence it is more efficient even if it looks horrible (and for a graphics library efficiency really matters)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class Data with an attribute Percentage. Something like:

```
public class Data {

    private String percentage;

    public Data() {
    }

    public String getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

Then, you can call:

```
Data d = wooot.getData();
String percentage = d.getPercentage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without paying attention to what you are trying to accomplish, I think the "general purpose" solution for this problem would be to return an instance of a new class that wrapped both values.

```
    public static class DataResults
{
    private final String percent;
    private final String name;
    public DataResults(String percent, String name) {
        super();
        this.percent = percent;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
public static DataResults getData(String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .get();
    String percent = doc.select(".percent-remaining").first().text();
    String name = doc.select("h2").first().text();
    return new DataResults(percent, name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you think you need multiple results from a method, you're really trying to represent something conceptually more complicated than two separate values.  You're actually trying to represent two results *and the relationship between them*.  Take, for instance, the idea of integer division, when you care about both the result and the remainder.  The first option would be to just define two separate methods, `divide()`, and `mod()`.  The problem is now a) you do the same operation twice, and b) you separate obviously connected logic.  You're not actually trying to return two pieces of data, you're trying to return one, more complicated result.

```
public class DivMod {
  public final int result;
  public final int remainder;
  // standard constructor, getters aren't strictly necessary in such a simple class
}

public static DivMod divMod(int dividend, int divisor) {
  // compute remainder, result
  return new DivMod(remainder, result);
}
```

This snippet hopefully makes it clear that there's often there's something even better you could do - do the computation *in* the object:

```
public class DivMod {
  private final int dividend, divisor, result, remainder;

  public DivMod(int dividend, int divisor) {
    this.dividend = dividend;
    this.divisor = divisor;
    // calculate and set result and remainder
  }

  // standard getters
}
```

Now we've really compartmentalized what we're trying to do with proper Object Oriented Programming.  There's no need for a static method, and all the logic is clearly in one place.  Even better, we avoid the above case where a meaningless `DivMod` is constructed (one that doesn't actually represent a division result).  We guarantee that every `DivMod` instance is an immutable result of integer division.

---

There are two standard alternatives to the above, both of which are anti-patterns.  The first is to return an array or a Collection, and the second is to define some sort of general `Tuple` class that holds multiple arbitrary data types.  While tuples at least offer the benefit of being a fixed size, and the ability to hold different types in the same object, they are terribly poor alternatives to a proper OOP design.  Guava offers some insight in their [Idea Graveyard](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard), as well.

See also @RichardTingle's suggestion of passing a mutable object into your method in order to update it with additional data, but consider this strictly a last resort option; it generally introduces far more confusion than benefit.

Answer (score -1):

You can use String[] and return an Array of Strings.

Comment: They are better ways, like creating a class holding the data.

Comment: yeah you are right, i didn't think of this possibility