# Return Muitiple Int Values From Method java

Tags: java

I want to return tow values from fallow method
public  Double MyCalc(double a, double n)
    {
         a=a/2;
        double d;
        double m;
        double l;
        double q=0;
        double af=0;

```
    if (n <= 100000000)
    {
        d = n * 0.5 / 100;
        af = (d * a / 100);
        q = d;
       // x1 = af;
        return q;
    }
```

I want return q and x1

Comment: wrap in a Object and return a single object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786779/113632

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class for that and return an instance of it.

```
class QAndX1ButWithABetterNameDependingOnYourApp{
    double q;
    double x1;
}
```

As a next step, it could make sense to move the whole calculation into that class as well:

```
static QAndX1 calculate(double a, double b, double c){
    // ... some calculations
    return new QAndX1(q,x1);
}
```

Comment: How To impliment This Method??